# Accessing(Selecting) file that is currently being written to

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, freeze

I have application which continuously writes to a .txt file (it is a log file).
When I try to even select this file from windows explorer (at which point it is being written to presumably by the application) windows explorer starts to hang. Is this expected behaviour? Or something is wrong with my program?

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: @Ramhound: can't check it now afraid it will repeat hang. But I doubt it was too big .. maybe it was antivirus related also?? it is kaspersky endpoint security 10 (can't turn it off now, will check that later)